# Converting sentence with multiple nouns (each having own adjective) into a je-desto Satz

Tags: grammar-identification, comparative

> Convert to Je-desto Satz
>
> Question: **Manche** Familien haben **viele** Kinder. Die Kinder verhalten sich sozial. je...desto.
>
> Soltn: Je **manche(er)** Familie **mehrer** Kinder haben, desto verhalte ndie Kinder sich sozial.

Is my solution correct? I am confused whether I should convert only one adjective or both. To me, I think both could sound right...?

Comment: You're treating "manche" like an adjective, which it isn't. And you're not treating "sozial", which in fact is an adjective, like one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is a bit of an unlucky choice: What you want to learn is that "je...desto" sentences put the attributive adjectives in both parts into the Komparativ and bracket the two parts with "Je...desto".

In the first part, the "where is the adjective?" question is a bit hard to answer (and that's the unlucky choice): "Manche" is an indefinite pronoun - the above rule cannot be used here, because (most) indefinite pronouns cannot be put into the comparative. Thus, your sentences are both wrong.

What *could* then be the "adjective" in the first part? The only other possible choice is "viele", which is, unfortunately, not a ("real") adjective as well, but **does** have a Komparativ, so the only choice here.

In the second part, there's no such choice - The only adjective there is "sozial".

So, your solution is:
Put both "viel" and "sozial" in the comparative, then add the "je...desto" bracket. Ends up as

> Je mehr Kinder eine Familie hat, desto sozialer verhalten sich die Kinder

Comment: Wdym it is not a real adjective?

Comment: How does manche fit in here?